# Como enviar e-mail automaticamente?

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Como enviar e-mails automaticamente usando o PHP?

Tenho um formulário que recebe várias datas e quando faltasse 10 dias para terminar o prazo, envia-se uma mensagem à várias pessoas com o aviso.

Já me disseram para usar o *Cron job*. Mas isso serve só para fazer a rotina executar.

Preciso é de ajuda no código porque estive a experimentar por o código no gestor de tarefas do Windows e nada.

```
<?php 
include(conectar.php);
$conn = @mysql_connect($local_serve, $usuario_serve, $senha_serve, $banco_de_dados)
    or die ("O servidor não responde!");

// conecta-se ao banco de dados
$db = @mysql_select_db($banco_de_dados,$conn)
    or die ("Não foi possivel ligar-se a Base de Dados!");

$validade = ("SELECT Nome, AlvaraValidade, AcidenteValidade, SeguroValidade, FinancasValidade, SocialValidade, RemuneracaoValidade, InstaladorValidade, MontadorValidade, MedicaValidade, ProjectistaValidade, GasValidade, RedesValidade, SoldadorValidade, MecanicoValidade, ClasSoldadorValidade, MaquinaValidade1, MaquinaValidade2, MaquinaValidade3, MaquinaTopoValidade FROM tb_eqipamentos, tb_detalhe_trabalhador, tb_trabalhador");
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now ($validade);

if ($diff <= 10){
    $mail_to = "MAIL@MAIL.pt";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['name']." - ".$row['email']."\n";
    $mail_to = $row['email'].", ";
}
if (!empty($mail_to)){
    sendEmail($mail_to);
}

?>
```

Comment: O que seria regas?

Comment: Melhore seu código, está tudo "amontoado" e assim dificulta pra quem quer te ajudar.

Comment: @user3253195, evite usar `<?` (no lugar use `<?php` , `@` (pode usar por exemplo `isset()`) e as funções `mysql_` já foram depreciadas. para não ter problemas futuros.

Comment: @user3253195, O php vai rodar em um servidor linux ou windows? Para servidores Windows tem que adicionar os dados de um servidor smtp nas configurações do PHP, já no caso se um servidor linux o PHP usa o sendmail para enviar. Seu problema pode está acontecendo nesse ponto.

Comment: Será para usar num servidor Windows. 
Ah secalhar falta-me mesmo essa parte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece mesmo que o seu problema está na configuração do servidor de e-mail.

Quando preciso enviar e-mail à partir do windows, eu uso o sendmail para windows ou configuro uma conexão smtp.

Para o sendmail, que é mais rápido, basta acessar o site abaixo e fazer o download do zip.

http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

Para funcionar no PHP, eu o descompacto na pasta C:\usr\lib\sendmail.
Localize a seguinte linha no seu php.ini local:

`;sendmail=`

Descomente-a para que ela fique da maneira abaixo:

`sendmail_path = "C:/usr/lib/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t -i"`

Para mim sempre funciona.

Comment: Desculpa? A ver se percebi.
Tenho de descompactar a pasta zip e coloca-la onde? Estou a utilizar o Wamp para testar.
No fim tenho :
sendMail($item, $mail_from, $mail_to, $subject, $mensagem);

Tenho de alterar para o sendmail_path? ou acrescentar?

Comment: Crie as seguinte pasta recursivamente.
C:/usr/lib/sendmail/
Descompacte os arquivos nela.

Answer (score 2):

Use esta minha função, basta chamá-la com as 3 variáveis com valores seus.

```
function EnviarMail($destinatario, $assunto, $mensagem)
{
    $de = "no-reply@mail.com";
    $headers = "From: O_TEU_NOME <".$de.">\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: Text/HTML; charset=UTF-8\n";

    // formatação da mensagem em HTML
    $mensagem = '<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
    <body>
    ' . $mensagem . '
    </body>
    </html>';

    $ok = mail($destinatario,$assunto,$mensagem,$headers);

    return $ok;
}
```

Comment: Irei usar só php . 
Mais ou menos como tens ai e com as alterações que deu o @perdeu

Comment: este código é todo php

Answer (score 2):

Use [datediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) do mysql para efetuar o calcula entre as data.

```
$validade = ("SELECT Nome, AlvaraValidade, AcidenteValidade, 
SeguroValidade, FinancasValidade, SocialValidade, RemuneracaoValidade,
....//sql longo);
```

`$validade`é somente uma string e não uma consulta, é necessario usar `mysql_query()` para excuta-la. Caso o resultado for mais de uma linha utlilze um `while` em conjunto com `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

seu código deve ficar dessa forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT <campos> FROM tb_eqipamentos, tb_detalhe_trabalhador, tb_trabalhador  
WHERE datediff(now(), data) = 10 "

$validade = mysql_query($sql);

while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($validade)){
    //enviar emails
    sendMail($item['email'];
}
```

Recomendo dar uma olhada em [inner join](http://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016), para melhorar a legibilidade e a performace de sua consulta.

Comment: Exacto, quero usar essa forma.Depois no meio e colocar? $To = $Subject = $Message = $Headers = "

Comment: @user3253195, no lugar de `//enviar emails` vc coloca os outros códidgos, lembre que assunto e mensagem pode ser o mesmo conteudo então podem ficar fora do `while`

Answer (score 2):

Consegui fazer com que o Php envia-se email. 
Acabei por utilizar o PhpMailer. Deixo o codigo para quem necessitar. Obrigado a todos

```
$PHPMailer = new PHPMailer();

// define que será usado SMTP
$PHPMailer->IsSMTP();

// envia email HTML
$PHPMailer->isHTML( true );

// codificação UTF-8, a codificação mais usada recentemente
$PHPMailer->Charset = 'UTF-8';

// Configurações do SMTP
$PHPMailer->SMTPAuth = True;
$PHPMailer->SMTPSecure = '....';
$PHPMailer->Host = '....';
$PHPMailer->Port = '25';
$PHPMailer->Username = '....';
$PHPMailer->Password = '....';

// E-Mail do remetente (deve ser o mesmo de quem fez a autenticação
// nesse caso seu_login@gmail.com)
$PHPMailer->From = '....';

// Nome do rementente
$PHPMailer->FromName = '....';

// assunto da mensagem
$PHPMailer->Subject = '.....';

// corpo da mensagem
$PHPMailer->Body = '<p>Mensagem em HTML</p>';

// corpo da mensagem em modo texto
$PHPMailer->AltBody = 'Mensagem em texto';

// adiciona destinatário (pode ser chamado inúmeras vezes)
$PHPMailer->AddAddress( '......' );

// adiciona um anexo
$PHPMailer->AddAttachment( '' );

// verifica se enviou corretamente
if ( $PHPMailer->Send() )
{
echo "Enviado com sucesso";
}
else
 {
echo 'Erro do PHPMailer: ' . $PHPMailer->ErrorInfo;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Qual é o problema que esta recebendo ?

Exibe algum erro na tela?

Pelo que percebo em seu código, você verifica se a validade é menor que 10 e não executa mais nada.

O ponto inicial para envio de e-mail é [verificar se seu servidor aceita mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php)

Caso seu servidor não aceitar mail, você deverá efetuar o envio utilizando SMTP. Começe pelo básico disparando e-mail com a função `mail` ou uma [classe de envio SMTP](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: Bem-vindo. De fato falta informações na pergunta e você ainda não pode pedir mais detalhes em comentário até ter mais reputação. Quando puder, edite a resposta para manter só o que responde à pergunta.

Comment: Tenho de instalar algo por causa do SMTP? Peço desculpa pelas perguntas mas é a primeira vez a Aventurar-me por esses campos

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é deixar esta página aberta em um navegador dando *refresh* de tempo em tempo...

Para isto você pode utilizar o código abaixo (o valor do *content* é em segundos):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Comment: Que código abaixo?

Comment: Adicionei ali..

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma maneira estranha mais funcional de você usar essa rotina, eu colocaria no *login master*, que pode ser o ID = 1, fazer uma pesquisa se for a condição que você quer ele executa a sua função, se não continua. deu para entender?

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você está dizendo, não é sobre isso a pergunta. Fazer a tarefa rodar não é o problema, o problema parece ser que o código de envio de email não funciona.